# How can I convert Day number in Date type to ordinal number word. E.g. 16/03/2021 to sixteenth/03/2021

Tags: sql, oracle

Input: Formatted Datetime as DD/MM/YYYY

Output: ordinal_number_word/MM/YYYY

Comment: @OldProgrammer - just making sure you see the answer by pmdba. There is a format mask for that.

Answer (score 2):

Use the to_char function to format dates and timestamps to be whatever you need in terms of format:

```
select to_char(sysdate,'ddSPTH/MM/YYYY') from dual;

TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'ddSPTH/MM/YYYY') 
--------------------------------- 
sixteenth/03/2021
```

If you are taking text input, then something like this:

```
select to_char(to_date('16/03/2021','DD/MM/YYYY'),'DDSPTH/MM/YYYY') from dual;
```

See here:

- https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/TO_CHAR-datetime.html#GUID-0C3EEFD1-AE3D-452D-BF23-2FC95664E78F
- https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Format-Models.html#GUID-515DFB76-E853-432F-BFEC-F1C62306BEC5

Comment: Using dd instead of DD in the format model will match the OP's request exactly. (He shows the day-of-the-month in lowercase text.)